# Why my flutter app launcher icon in a circle? Can I use a square icon to replace this one?

Tags: android, flutter

I was using the following website to generate several launcher icons for my flutter app.

https://romannurik.github.io/AndroidAssetStudio/icons-launcher.html

But after I replace the original flutter icons ( file path: myapp/android/app/src/main/res ) and run my app, my icon is in a circled icon. ( check the image I attached )

[image: My icon in app launcher]

My Android Virtual Device is Nexus 5X API 28.

So can anyone tell me what was wrong? And Can I use a square icon to replace this one?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The launcher that comes on the emulator forces all icons to be round. If the icon isn't already round, it will add a round border around it, like you see in that screenshot.

This isn't something you can change. If you want your icon to be square, use a different launcher. It's ultimately up to the user how their icons display.

You may want to consider implementing [adaptive icons](https://developer.android.com/guide/practices/ui_guidelines/icon_design_adaptive), so if a user does use circle or squircle icons and their icon pack/launcher forces all icons to be round, it at least won't look terrible.

Comment: "If the icon isn't already round" - all my PNG, JPG and other files are rectangles. How do I save a round icon?