# create circle mipmap launcher icon for all of API

Tags: android, icons, android-mipmap

I created circle icon for my app by illustrator.
My icon in api 21 is circle. But it's not circle in api 27.
what do I create circle in api 27?

Comment: You should create an adaptive icon https://developer.android.com/guide/practices/ui_guidelines/icon_design_adaptive. But keep in mind that at the end of the day, how icons display is up to the device vendor

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why my flutter app launcher icon in a circle? Can I use a square icon to replace this one?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52726619/why-my-flutter-app-launcher-icon-in-a-circle-can-i-use-a-square-icon-to-replace)